# Download SCORM from Moodle

Tags: moodle, scrape, scorm

I am a newbie to SCORM.

We need to crawl e-learning portals and index data found in SCORM 1.2 objects. Is there a way to download these SCORM objects from Moodle and subsequently read them?

If crawling is out of the question and we can acquire the SCORM objects, is it possible read the contents of the SCORM objects? E.g., we'd like to extract text from these objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, SCORM content is E-Learning content, it is not downloadable..
It was developed to be used on web pages only, so there's no way to extract data..
Unless you pen it down on paper!

Answer (score 0):

I'll break the question down into two parts.

#### 1. How do I obtain the resources of a deployed SCORM course?

Each SCORM package contains a file called `imsmanifest.xml`. This file has a `resources` element that contains a list of the different files contained in the package. The LMS I've encountered do not usually prevent access to this file if you're authenticated, so if you have access to the course, you could parse the manifest and download each referenced file. Note that the resources section may not list all files. For example, XML schemas (usually referenced by `imsmanifest.xml` itself) and manually added files may not be present in the manifest.

#### 2. How do I extract data from SCORM packages?

The answer to this depends on the authoring package used and its version. Prior to the deprecation of Adobe Flash, you would find a lot of these courses are Flash-based, and may contain data in `.swf` files or other formats that are easy to load in Flash. These days, most courses are HTML5, so you would find typical web formats like `.png`, `.jpg`, `.mp4`, etc. However, these files may be encapsulated, for example encoded into base64 and stored in JSON files. Text data may be separate, or may be compiled into JavaScript files that you would need to parse through and extract. It's highly dependent on the course runtime, so I would suggest digging through the files after you have downloaded a copy of the package.